# css, Keep 2 elements on same line. Cut width of second element to stay on line

Tags: html, css

I need two lines of text to be on the same line. I do not know the lengths of these texts. If the combined text length exceeds the parent's width, then the second line of text should be cut off. The text should not be pushed down.

Plain float doesn't work because it pushes the second line down:

```
<div style = "width:250px">
    <div style = "max-width:250px;float:left">
        I have priority 1
    </div>
    <div style = "float:left">
        I get what is left over
    </div>
</div>
```

I made a jsfiddle to show **what it should look like:**

http://jsfiddle.net/hvhRC/2/.

However, it needs to look like this without hardcoding the widths of the text lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/4LP6w/)

html

```
<div class="one-line">
    <div>this is the first line, priority</div>
    <div>this is the second</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.one-line {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    white-space: nowrap; /* forces both child divs to stay a single line */
    font-size: 0px; /* removes a small amount of whitespace between child inline-block elements */
}

.one-line > div {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12pt; /* corrects font to normal size, 0px is inherited from .one-line */
}

.one-line > div:first-child {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.one-line > div:last-child {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%; /* forces width of 2nd element to fill the rest of the space (additional width is hidden from parent's overflow property) */
}
```